# Fill remaining LIMIT rows selection if conditions met are less than LIMIT number

Tags: mysql, order-by, limits

I have a MySQL database with data in it. They all have locations (London, Liverpool, etc), I want a query to select 10 random rows with a location (for example London), and if there aren't enough to satisfy the LIMIT request then fill the remaining rows with random other ones, so, for example, 10 random rows requested from London, but I only have 7 with London as the location, so it'll get the 7 from London and 3 from any other location.

The query is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 'yes' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

This brings them randomly, and if I put "AND location = '$location'" then it gets from the specified location (calling using PHP where $location is a variable stating the priority location), but if there's less than 10, it'll only bring those rows, nothing more. I have no idea how to add extra random filler rows if it doesn't reach 10 at the priority location

Answer (score 2):

As Akina helpfully stated in their comment, all I did to resolve this was write the query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 'yes' 
 ORDER BY location = '$location' DESC, RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Comment: `'$location'` looks like it's not parameterized, **always** parameterize data passed into a query